# Qt 4.7 SSL error : "The certificate has expired”

Tags: qt, ssl, openssl

We compiled the QT code using the OpenSSL libraries. But we are not able to load the HTTPS webpages. The SSL Error handler is throwing “The certificate has expired” exception.  we used http://orkut.com to test the SSL issues.

What was happening before we recompiled Qt source?

Following errors, when we tried to launch HTTPS urls

```
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_error_string
```

What we did?

1. Download and install Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.0d Light
2. Open VS2008 command prompt
3. Navigate to “C:\Qt\4.7.1”
4. `configure.exe -debug-and-release -webkit -openssl -I C:\OpenSSL-Win32\Include -L C:\OpenSSL-Win32\Lib`
5. `nmake`

Error After compiling with openSSL dll

1. when we try to load SSL url using webview , we get the following error
2. “The certificate has expired”
3. We handled the networkAccessManager `sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)` event which showed as the “certificate expired” error.
4. We are unclear about what additional settings are needed to fix this issue

---

when i tested my code in a 32 bit system, the OpenSSL dll worked as per expected. when i use a 64 bit system i get the “certificate expired” error. i am using Qt creator 32 bit version to run my code in the 64 bit system. also i am using OpenSSL 32 bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if system's date is ok?

**UPDATE**
It looks like you have problem with 32/64 bit mismatch.
If your app is 64bit you should use 64bit version of OpenSSL. Install 64bit OpenSSL and make sure it's in the PATH when running your app from within Creator (you can add OpenSSL's path to PATH in Projects/Run Settings/Run Environment)

Comment: This is always the first check to do. Seen it happen over and over again.

Comment: i checked my system date. everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't deployed properly - Qt is unable to find the openssl DLL at runtime which is why you're getting the cannot call unresolved function messages. No idea why you'd get the expired certificate error in combination with this though.

Comment: I guess you missed *What was happening **before** we recompiled Qt source?* part of the question. Errors regarding unresolved functions were present **before** they recompiled Qt library.

Comment: as  Piotr Dobrogost pointed out, the unresolved error was before we compiled with OpenSSL. i copied the OpenSSL "ssleay32.dll" and "libeay32.dll" to C:\Qt\4.7.1\bin before i launched the browser application. one more strange behavior i noticed during testing was, when i used the OpenSSL version "Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.0d Light" i got the "Certificate Error" and when i used "Win32 OpenSSL v0.9.8r Light" i started getting "no Error" messages from the sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>) SIGNAL